Movie where monster can only come out in the dark. (Not Lights Out)
Ok so recently this new movie "Lights Out" is coming out and I remember seeing something like it when I was young it was like lights out because the monster/creature only came out in the dark, I don't remember much else about the movie but I'm pretty sure it ended in a light house or something (I am aware I haven't included many details but this is all I can remember from the movie as its been at least 5 years since I last saw it.) It was a horror movie.

Could be Darkness Falls
The monster (The tooth fairy) was afraid of the light, so the lead character was always carrying flash lights. 
The movie also ended in a lighthouse.
The ending scene (From Wikipedia) :

Kyle loses his bag of flashlights but gains allies as others realize his story is true. Matilda is determined to kill Kyle, whom she could not conquer. Kyle, Michael, and Caitlin hide in the local lighthouse; the largest light source in the town. They are helped by several medical personnel, all of whom are killed by Matilda on the way.
Pursued by Matilda, they discover the lighthouse has defective wiring, which they try to repair. Their only protection is two small kerosene lanterns that have insufficient oil. During the struggle, Matilda tries to kill Kyle, but before she can do so, the lighthouse lights up. The sudden exposure to light caused Matilda pain; she drops her mask and it shatters. Kyle can see her disfigured face and realizes she is now vulnerable. She resumes her attack, during which Kyle's right sleeve catches fire and he kills Matilda by striking her face with it.




